# Return Variable change between form_closing and Program.cs

Tags: c#, .net, global-variables

I have a global variable Program.intReturnVal which isn't always getting back to the calling app.

This particular catch block is the one that's failing. It has all the same code as the others which are working correctly. The someMethod() is actually calling a stored procedure if that matters:

```
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GlobalClass.WriteToTextFile(ErrorLogFile, "Exception Error: someMethod() failed." + Environment.NewLine + "Additional details: " + ex.ToString(), ErrorLogPath);
                Program.intReturnVal = ErrorCode;
                Form.ActiveForm.Close();
            }
```

The value of Program.intReturnVal at this point is 900

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Inside form closing block - " + Program.intReturnVal);

    }
```

The value of Program.intReturnVal at this point is 900

```
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Inside form closed block - " + Program.intReturnVal);

    }
```

The value of Program.intReturnVal at this point is 900.

Now... in the Program.cs page:

```
static class Program
{
    public static int intReturnVal;
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static int Main()
    {
        intReturnVal = 900; // Zero is success 900 is error
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        try
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        catch
        {
            intReturnVal = 900;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Inside Program.cs block " + Program.intReturnVal + " " + intReturnVal);
        return intReturnVal;
    }
}
```

The value of Program.intReturnVal at this point is 0. What is resetting it to 0? Could it be in the Dispose method?

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);

    }
```

Should I add an error code to the parameters in the form closing and closed methods? This seems silly to me since I have already seen the value is 900 at those points.

TIA for any help.

Comment: Well, this is at least one of the reasons that a public static field is evil.  Make it a property, set a breakpoint on the setter, now you can debug it.

Comment: If I use System.Environment.Exit(ErrorCode) instead of Form.ActiveForm.Close() it works, but it doesn't go through Program.cs. It does what I need it to do for the most part, but I know there must be a better way. I'll look into Hans' suggestion.